# addTarget() does not work on custom extensions

Tags: swift

I made a custom `UIView()` and i'm trying to add a okButton to it.

However. I have added the button but when showing my UIView in one of my ViewControllers, But the button won't work. This is my code:

```
class Luna: UIView {

let luna = UIView()
let okButton = UIButton()
typealias completionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void


// Not yet implemented
open var touchOutsideToHide: Bool = true;

private var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    okButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
    okButton.setTitle("Okay", for: .normal)
    okButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 16)

    let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(_:)))
    okButton.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

}

```
 //The target function
@objc func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton){ //<- needs `@objc`
    // .. //
    print("btn hit")
}
```

I do not get `btn hit` in the console and the tap isn't registered

the button is visible, it's added as a subview: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMSf.png)

Comment: Why would you add a gesture recognizer to a button?

Comment: @Desdenova to detect touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button have default touch gesture, you don't need to add it. just add target as follow to fix your issue. Create protocol of your customer class and declare delegate for it in same class as follow.

```
protocol LunaDelegate: class {
    func okButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)
}

class Luna: UIView {

    let luna = UIView()
    let okButton = UIButton()
    typealias completionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void

    weak var delegate: LunaDelegate?

    // Not yet implemented
    open var touchOutsideToHide: Bool = true;

    private var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        okButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        okButton.setTitle("Okay", for: .normal)
        okButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 16)
        okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if let selfDelegate = self.delegate {
        selfDelegate.okButtonTapped(sender: sender)
    }
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then after implement your code as follow to use your custom view. When your button will pressed then delegate method will be call in your view controller.

**Usage:**

```
class LunaViewController: UIViewController, LunaDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let luna = Luna(frame: CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 40))
        luna.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(luna)
    }

    // MARK:- Luna Delegate
    func okButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        print("OK Button Pressed From Luna View")
    }
}
```

This is the proper solution which I have already using in my current project. I hope this will help you.